# Open folder in Dropbox from my android app

Tags: android, dropbox

I need to open specific Dropbox folder in Dropbox app by calling it from my app. I know only two similar solutions:

- opening by Intent chooser, but i need exactly open it for viewing, not for choosing files;
- calling Dropbox app by PackageManager, but it just open Dropbox app, when i need open a folder in Dropbox app.

I prefer second way, so i use code like this:

```
PackageManager manager = context.getPackageManager();
Intent i = manager.getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.dropbox.android");
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);    
context.startActivity(i);
```

Is there a way to transfer a folder path to Dropbox app?
Or how i can open folder in Dropbox app in the other way?

---

**SUMMARY:**

Dropbox API hasn't that feature. So, i decided to choose other way to solve that problem. I just open the folder by web url in android web browser. Like that:

```
String fullUrl = "https://www.dropbox.com/home/Apps/APP/" + folderAdress;
Intent browserIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(fullUrl));
context.startActivity(browserIntent);
```

It's work slowly and not so comfortably, but it works...

Comment: There currently isn't an API to do this, but we're tracking it as a feature request.

Comment: Greg, thanks for answer, i think it will be useful feature.